# Angular: Add Text to an Existing Input Field on Button Click Where Input and Button are rendered by two different component

Tags: angular

[Related Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45826664/add-text-to-an-existing-input-field-on-button-click)
But this is not exactly the same.
I have two components. One component has the input, another component has a button. Now I want to populate some text on click of the button in the input field which is rendered by a different component.

input.component.html

```
<input #input type="text-area"/>
```

button.component.html

```
<li (click)="addText($event)">Click Me !!</li>
```

button.component.ts

```
@ViewChild('input') private input; addText(event){
    console.log(this.input); //this is undefined 
}
```

Project Structure :

- ./input/input.component.ts
- ./input/input.component.html
- ./button/button.component.ts
- ./button/button.component.html

I know I can use a service and then have an observable to listen to and subscribe to that for identifying the changes, but I just wanted to avoid that, as the accepted answer in the hyperlink above looked simpler.

Comment: you need to do this using a service. raise an event from the service from button component and subscribe to that event in input component and add the text there. Can you share a sample app for the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the example in the link, I suggest the following solution. 
As the two components are siblings, use `@Viewchild` to get the reference of the children DOM elements. `@Input` and `@Output` will help for the communication.

**parent.component.html**

```
   <div class="wrapper">
      <comp1 #comp1 [myText]="name"></comp1>
      <comp2 (clickEvent)="addText()"></comp2>
   </div>
```

**parent.component.ts**

```
  import { ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
  ...

  name = 'Angular'; 

  @ViewChild('comp1') private comp1;

  addText(event) {
    this.comp1.myInput.nativeElement.focus();
    let startPos = this.comp1.myInput.nativeElement.selectionStart;
    let value = this.comp1.myInput.nativeElement.value;
    this.comp1.myInput.nativeElement.value =
      value.substring(0, startPos) + ' rocks! ' + value.substring(startPos, value.length)
  }
```

**button.component.html**

```
  <ul>
     <li (click)="clickEventMethod()"> Click here to add some text </li>
  </ul>
```

**button.component.ts**

```
  import { Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
  ...
  @Output() clickEvent = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

  clickEventMethod() {
    this.clickEvent.emit();
  }
```

**input.component.html**

```
  <input [(ngModel)]="myText" #myInput type="text" placeholder="Enter some text">`,
```

**input.component.ts**

```
   import { ViewChild, Input } from '@angular/core';
   ...
   @ViewChild('myInput') private myInput;
   @Input() private myText;
```

**[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ewvtmr)**

Comment: button.component.html does not have <input-component #comp></input-component>

Comment: This works, so accepting it. Though I have used a service based approach as some specs changed and needed to make it more generic.

Answer (score 0):

Use a separate service to do this. You can push values from the button component to the service from calling a set method on service. And you can get values from the service to the input component by using a subject and subscribing to it. Hope this helps.